# Cocos2d-X why call retain() before addChild()

Tags: cocos2d-x, retain, addchild

Can anybody help me to find out why we need to call the retain() before the addChild(), I just thought if we call the addChild, the pool will manage the CCNode we added, so why we need to retain it and release it by ourself?

```
bool GameOverScene::init()
{

    if( CCScene::init() )
    {
        this->_layer = GameOverLayer::create();
        this->_layer->retain();
        this->addChild(_layer);

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

GameOverScene::~GameOverScene()
{

    if (_layer)
    {
        _layer->release();
        _layer = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the answer is once we have the class member variable which is a CCNode*, then we need to call the retain for it?

Comment: Actually if you even remove retain and release calls, all should work fine. Node is retained after being added to some parent. Of course, until parent exists.

Comment: @Morion: sure but it is fragile to depend on that. It is just always easier to retain instance variables as a general rule, and not have to think about whether a particular variable may be retained by something else.

Comment: @newacct: by your logic it is normal to retain object after adding it to array and release after removing.

Comment: @Morion: no, because an element of an array is not an instance variable. If you mean regular C array, then yes. If you mean a specialized collection class, then no. The collection retains its elements instead.

Comment: @newacct: ok. you say that collection retains it's elements. but all nodes retain their children too. so where is the difference? why do you say not to retain elements in collection. but to retain children of some parent node?

Comment: @Morion: I didn't say to retain children of some parent node. I only said to retain instance variables. `this->_layer` is an instance variable, therefore it is retained. If you just put the layer in as a child but don't keep an instance variable to it, then it doesn't need to be retained. Conversely, if you have some element of a collection that you also keep as an instance variable, then you also retain it, because it is an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the memory management in Cocos2D-X, which is written in C++. However, if it is similar to the reference-counting memory management in Cocoa, then every time you set an instance variable, you should release the previous value and retain the new value.

Sure, in this case, we happen to know that by adding it as a child to ourselves, it will also be retained there. However, it makes your code fragile by relying on something else to retain it. So every time you create an instance variable, you have to think about whether it may be retained by something else, and you have to remember this decision everywhere you use this variable. It is better to just consistently always retain instance variables. It never hurts to retain it more times.

Comment: Can you help me to find out anther question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, but I met another question:

```
void TextureCacheTestScene::runThisTest()
{

    CCLayer* pLayer = new TextureCacheTest(); // not add the reference for pLayer
    addChild(pLayer); // add 1

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(this);
    pLayer->release(); // delete 1
}
```

Why we need to call release() after the replaceScene()?
I just find the replaceScene add the reference for the scene not the layer, so I feel confused with what happened:

1. addChild(pLayer)   // add reference for the pLayer;
2. relplaceScene()   // add reference for the scene;(don't add referen for the pLayer)
3. pLayer->release() // delete reference for the pLayer;
   So why the pLayer is not be recycled? I don't think if the scene is alive then the pLayer can not be recycled, I believe the reference account will not care that.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question (in fact has nothing to do with your question), so should not be here. You should really start a new question.

But if Cocos2d-X memory management is like Cocoa memory management, then `new TextureCacheTest()` looks just like `[[TextureCacheTest alloc] init]` in Cocoa. In other words, it returns something that you "own", i.e. it is already retained once. Hence, it needs to be balanced with a `release` at the end of the scope.